# Prevent linebreaks in Prettier

Tags: prettier

How can I prevent prettier from adding line breaks to the beginning of my `.then()` and `.catch()` statements

### Expected

```
  await Axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: test,
  }).then((response) => {
      ...
  }).catch((exception) => {
      ...
  });
```

### Actual

```
  await Axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: test,
  })
  .then((response) => {
      ...
  })
  .catch((exception) => {
      ...
  });
```